# algorithm: return the minimum number of terms with the power x that get to sum y

Tags: algorithm

When I was reading this geeksforgeeks page
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-power-terms-with-sum-equal-to-n/

I start wondering if we switch this problem a little bit, instead of getting minimum number of power terms with sum equal to n, we write a function minPower(power,sum):

minPower(2,7) returns 4, because 7 = 2^2+1^2+1^2+1^2

minPower(2,9) returns 1, because 9=3^2

minPower(3,9) returns 2, because 9=2^3+1^3

How should I write such function?

Comment: Why would `minPower(2,7)` not return 2 - 2^2 + 3^1?

Comment: It is an easy recursion: iterate over the first number and determine the minPower of the rest. To optimize implement some pruning.

Comment: @BobJarvis hey! because all the power terms have to be the ones specified in the parameters, which here power=2, so each term has to have x^2, so 3^1 isn't valid.

Comment: @Henry I am sorry but I am very very bad at algo, is it possible for you to give me a pseudocode about it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this is to use a recursive greedy algorithm, removing the largest number `m <= sum`, where `m = p^n`, until sum is 0, in which case you've found a solution, or negative, in which case you reduce `p` by 1. Accept the solution with the minimum number of terms.

You can find the largest possible value of `p` using the term `pow(10, log10(sum)/n)`

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    minPower(2, 7);
}

public static void minPower(int n, int sum)
{
    if(n < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    int maxPow = (int)Math.pow(10, Math.log10(sum)/n);

    List<Integer> min = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> terms = new LinkedList<>();
    powers(n, sum, maxPow, terms, min);     
    System.out.println(min);
}

private static void powers(int n, int sum, int m, LinkedList<Integer> terms, List<Integer> min)
{
    if(sum == 0) 
    {
        if(min.isEmpty() || terms.size() < min.size())
        {
            min.clear();
            min.addAll(terms);
        }
        return;
    }
    else if(sum < 0) return;

    for(int i=m; i>0; i--)
    {
        terms.addLast(i);
        powers(n, sum - (int)Math.pow(i, n), i, terms, min);
        terms.removeLast();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2,7
[2, 1, 1, 1]

2, 9
[3]

3, 9
[2, 1]

3, 32
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Hey! if i want sum to be 32, and power =3, then the best return is supposed to be 4, because 2^3+2^3+2^3+2^3, but yours return [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] instead:o

Comment: You're right. I've modified the code to search for all solutions and accept the one with the minimum number of terms.